# Numba @guvectorise returns garbage values

Tags: python, arrays, numba

The code below is a test for calculating distance between points in a periodic system.

```python
import itertools
import time
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import njit

@njit(cache=True)
def get_dr(i=np.array([]),j=np.array([]),cellsize=np.array([])):
    k=np.zeros(3,dtype=np.float64)

    for idx, _ in enumerate(cellsize):
        k[idx] = (j[idx]-i[idx])-cellsize[idx]*np.round((j[idx]-i[idx])/cellsize[idx])
    return np.linalg.norm(k)


@numba.guvectorize(["void(float64[:],float64[:],float64[:],float64)"],
             "(m),(m),(m)->()",nopython=True,cache=True)
def get_dr_vec(i,j,cellsize,dr):
    dr=0.0
    k=np.zeros(3,dtype=np.float64)
    for idx, _ in enumerate(cellsize):
        k[idx] = (j[idx]-i[idx])-cellsize[idx]*np.round((j[idx]-i[idx])/cellsize[idx])

    dr=np.sqrt(np.square(k[0])+np.square(k[1])+np.square(k[2]))

N, dim = 50, 3  # 50 particles in 3D
vec = np.random.random((N, dim))

cellsize=np.array([26.4,26.4,70.0])
rList=[];rList2=[]

start = time.perf_counter()
for (pI, pJ) in itertools.product(vec, vec):
    rList.append(get_dr(pI,pJ,cellsize))
end =time.perf_counter()
print("Time {:.3g}s".format(end-start))

newvec1=[];newvec2=[]
start = time.perf_counter()
for (pI, pJ) in itertools.product(vec, vec):
    newvec1.append(pI)
    newvec2.append(pJ)
cellsizeVec=np.full(shape=np.shape(newvec1),fill_value=cellsize,dtype=float)
rList2=get_dr_vec(np.array(newvec1),np.array(newvec2),cellsizeVec)
end =time.perf_counter()
print("Time {:.3g}s".format(end-start))
print(rList2)
exit()
```

Compared to `get_dr()` which shows the correct result, `get_dr_vec()` shows garbage and `nan` values. The function `get_dr_vec()` is calculating the correct value for `dr`, but it returns garbage values with correct dimensions. Can someone suggest any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a small mistake in the `guvectorize` function call. Guvectorize does not want you to redefine the output variable, the output array/scalar must be filled in instead. The code below should work:

```
@numba.guvectorize(["void(float64[:],float64[:],float64[:],float64[:])"],
              "(m),(m),(m)->()",nopython=True, cache=True)
def get_dr_vec(i,j,cellsize,dr):
    k=np.zeros(3,dtype=np.float64)
    for idx, _ in enumerate(cellsize):
        k[idx] = (j[idx]-i[idx])-cellsize[idx]*np.round((j[idx]-i[idx])/cellsize[idx])
    
    # The mistake was on this line. You had "dr =", but it should be "dr[0] ="
    dr[0] = np.sqrt(np.square(k[0])+np.square(k[1])+np.square(k[2]))
```

The reason that `dr =` does not work is because guvectorize already allocates the `dr` array *before* you call the function. `dr =` messes things up because it places a new `dr` array in a new place in memory, so when numba looks at the original place in memory, where it expects to find an array, it instead finds nothing. `dr[0] =` does work, because that way, we can fill in the values in the original place in memory, where numba expect the values to be.

If it is still not 100% clear i recommend that you look through the [numba documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/0.56.4/user/vectorize.html) on this topic.

Those "garbage values" you were seeing was the output array that was never filled, similar to what you would see if you would call `print(np.empty(10))`

Comment: Thanks @Rafnus! Can you clarify more on why `dr[0]=0` instead of `dr=0`? My simplified understanding for `@guvectorize` was that the function has to written in for "minimal" dimensions, which can then be used for acting upon an array of inputs. For ex.: this function here calculates the distance between two points in 3-D toroidal space. The input has dimensions `(3,)` `(3,)` and returns a `float64` value.  So at least in the function definition it should be `dr=0` not  `dr[0]=0`. Or this is just to account for the ambiguity between defining `dr` as a scalar as well as a vector?

Comment: @mykd i edited my answer, hope this clears things up a bit

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have asked a further question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988222/speeding-up-vector-distance-calculation-using-numba).